# Is there a limit to the number of items a MS BIDS chart will show?

Tags: sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am using Microsoft BIDS 2012. I'm trying to organize data in a column chart, but only the first 40 data points are showing on the x axis. I've been looking online, but see nothing that indicates there's a maximum number of data points.

I have looked in the axis properties, but see nothing that is limiting the visibility of the data points. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Here's a picture of the chart data and chart:

[image]
[image]

EDIT: 
Here is my report data:
[image]
[image]

Here are my reporting fields:
[image]

Comment: Have you confirmed the dataset is returning more than 40 data points? (by just dumping the data into a table in the report for example)  Sometimes the data you are expecting isn't necessarily the data being returned.

Comment: @Jonnus Yes, I originally created the report. I have 43 data points. The chart picks up everything until the end of september, but no October data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any future people looking for this answer - the data points were on the chart, but they were sorted back to the left side. The data starts at January (1/xx/xxxx) then goes to October (10/xx/xxxx)